# Reset stored variable's value using psutil

Tags: python, psutil

**Greetings**

I'm trying to find how much CPU/RAM my python script using [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I make some simple loop to print the value of the CPU usage using `psutil.cpu_percent` but the only thing that gets printed is the first value.

Is there a way to, maybe reset the variable value after it's printed? Because when I use `top` to see how much CPU use from it, the result is different.

**Thank You**

**Looping Script**

```
import psutil
import time

p = psutil.Process(1594) #1594 is the PID of the script I want to observe
cpu_status = p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
n = 0

try:
        while n != 10:
                print(cpu_status)
                n = n + 1
                time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("quit")
```

**The Result**

```
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
87.9
```

I was expecting the result be like

```
87.9
89.0
88.1
70.2
80.4
87.9
89.0
88.1
70.2
80.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
It just simply put the variable inside the loop. Sorry to bother you, I have to learn more.

**Before**

```
p = psutil.Process(1594) #1594 is the PID of the script I want to observe
cpu_status = p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
n = 0

try:
        while n != 10:
                print(cpu_status)
                n = n + 1
                time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("quit")
```

**After fixed**

```
p = psutil.Process(1594) #1594 is the PID of the script I want to observe
n = 0

try:
        while n != 10:
                print(p.cpu_percent(interval=1))
                n = n + 1
                time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("quit")
```